# What are these so-called 'disasters' that improper use of pointers can cause?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, memory-management, unsafe-pointers

I've been using pointers more and more in my programs, and while reading up about pointers, every single guide or tutorial I found said that incorrect use of pointers could yield 'disastrous' results.

Now, I've had a few cases of some big memory leaks, and pointers dereferencing a wrong pointer variable, returning an incorrect value, but other than that nothing 'disastrous' has ever occurred; like my computer and/or other programs crashing.

Can someone give me a simple code example that will definitely yield 'disastrous' results, perhaps with some back-story of what happened, in case you've ever accidentally used that piece of code? By 'disastrous' results, I mean code that might interfere with other programs or the OS, and possibly make them crash.

Comment: Define "disastrous".  Misusing pointers can result in all sorts of big bugs in a program but on a modern computer the worst thing that will happen is that the program won't work as expected.

Comment: Well, don't operate an X-ray machine with a program that has pointer bugs.

Comment: @Peter Zion: I've read and heard from various sources that improper pointer use can actually cause your system to crash. Does this not hold true anymore for computers nowadays?

also: editing question

Comment: @Peter Zion: Using an invalid pointer is undefined behavior and it can manifest in any way. For example, if your program uses C++ runtime that has a function to delete all files deep inside that function might be called.

Comment: @Arcenio: Please look at this realworld answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908872/whats-the-worst-example-of-undefined-behaviour-actually-possible/3554343#3554343 Sending sensitive data over the network can be sometimes even worse than "crashing" your system.

Comment: Things were worse in the days of MS-DOS when a process's memory space wasn't locked down.  I remember bugs that caused random colourful characters to be sprayed on the screen (which lived at segment address 0xB800 as I recall) because you wrote (waaay) past the end of some buffer... :)

Comment: @Arcenio: it's relatively unusual in a modern OS for a normal user process to take down the whole system *by accident*, because the process model is supposed to isolate programs from each other and protect against that. But if you tickle a bug in the OS itself, or in some device driver running in a privileged mode, then it can be done (with or without explicit use of pointers, but they give you plenty of unique and exciting opportunities to invoke undefined behavior which the OS may or may not cope with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect pointer arithmetic can lead to disasters too, because getting the bounds wrong leads to buffer overflows, and buffer overflows lead to corrupted data, for example stack smashing:

```
void test_fun(int i)
    int x[5];
    for (int *p = x; p < x+10; ++p) { // obvious error, some are more subtle
        *p = i;
    }
    return; // execution may resume at address `i`, with entertaining results
}
```

Of course, you can make the same mistake just calling `strcpy` or `memcpy`[*], you don't have to be doing the pointer arithmetic yourself. If an attacker controls the value of `i` (perhaps because it's read from an input file, and the attacker crafts a malicious file), then you could have worse than a crash on your hands. In combination with more platform-specific tricks, the attacker might be able to arrange that returning to `i` eventually ends up executing code supplied by the attacker.

[*] or `strncpy`, or `strlcpy`, or `strcpy_s`, or `std::copy`, before anyone starts. Once you've got a bound wrong somehow, then supplying that wrong bound to a bounds-checking function is still wrong...

Answer (score 3):

There're two main kinds of disasters - dangling pointers and memory leaks.

Dangling pointer is when a pointer stores an address that is not an address of an object:

```
T* first;
T* second; //somewhere in another piece of code
first = new T();
second = first;
delete first;
first = 0; //second still stores the address of an already deleted object
```

memory leak is when there're no pointers storing an address of a heap-allocated object:

```
T* object;
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  object = new T();
}
delete object; // now the first nine objects are unreacheable
```

Dangling pointers are bad because using them you leads to undefined behavior - program might crash or modify some unrelated data and this will cause problems later. Memory leaks are bad because allocated memory can't be reused and so the program can get short on memory some time later.

Comment: +1. The 1st is usually worse than the 2nd, which just causes the program to waste memory (only important if the program is intended to run for a long time, like a server).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: It's worth remembering that leaked objects destructor won't be run and this might alter the program behavior.

Comment: it might be a typo, or me just being tired; but in your first example it seems like second is not a pointer. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

A few cases come to mind:

- continuing to access free()/delete()d memory or local variables after they've left scope
- leaking heap memory due to unclear ownership
- unintended shared access to data, where changes to pointed-to values may confuse some of algorithms working on them

  - accidental shallow copies
- incomplete/flawed serialisation due to naive binary writing of assumed POD data that actually contains pointers to other data
- multi-process unsafe data in shared memory where pointers (esp. virtual dispatch pointers) needed to be different in the different processes accessing it
- cyclic data linkage that causes code to get stuck in loops indefinitely
- moving the pointers through data in such a way that they accidentally move outside the data (the issue is similar to array indices, but more complex as there's not necessarily any constant reference and consistently safe relative indexing range)
- failing to check for / handle sentinel values correctly
- issues with the type of data to which the pointer points

  - use of unsafe/erroneous casts (e.g. a reinterpret cast where a dynamic cast is needed)
  - failure to appreciate that indexing from pointers is done in units of the pointer-to-type's size
  - invalid conversions from pointers to/from shorter integer types

Answer (score 0):

The most nasty I have seen are "delayed failures", when the wrongly done write access damages a data structure that is used only later, producing incorrect output of the completely irrelevant code. During debugging, you observe "the rise of machines" - the data structure mysteriously obtains the wrong values that have never been assigned, against the programmers will. You may be searching for an error thousands of LOC away from where it really is.